# AMQPlib callback API. Завершение consume по таймауту

Tags: javascript, callback

Есть вот такой простой код. Но нужно, чтобы consume завершался через определённое время. 
Пробовал ставить таймаут на соединение(10000), но это оказывается таймаут на рукопожатие.
Важно, не использовать setTime и setInterval
Какие есть варианты и идеи, как можно завершить consume или закрыть соединение через определённое время?

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', {timeout: 10000},function(error0, connection) {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
    connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
        if (error1) {
            console.log("ERROR")
            console.log(error1)
            throw error1;
        }
        var queue = 'task_queue';
        channel.assertQueue(queue, {
            durable: true
        });
        channel.prefetch(1);
        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);
        channel.consume(queue, function(msg) {
            channel.ack(msg);
            var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;
            console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
        }, {
            noAck: false
        });
    });
    /*
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("TIMEOUT")
        connection.close();
        process.exit(0)
    }, 10000);
    */
});
```

Comment: Важно, не использовать setTime и setInterval — почему?

Comment: @AlexeyTen я запускаю под vm2, там нет setTimeout, у меня нет возможности туда его прокинуть